# converting data url to a format that I can use to send to my backend web api and store in database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I am currently getting drag and drop / uploaded images as a data url and displaying them with that url.
What I am now trying to do is send those uploaded images to my backend web api using ASP.Net core to store then in a sqlite database this is a requirement for my application.

Currently I am converting the data url to an arraybuffer using the following code.

```
async srcToFile(context, asset) {
         const files = asset[0].files.fileList;
         let results = [];
         for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
             const file = files[i];
              const data = file.data;
              const name = file.name;
              const mimeType = file.type;

             await fetch(data)
                  .then(function(res) {
                      const r = res.arrayBuffer();
                      console.warn('resource ', r);
                      return r;
                  })
                  .then(function(buf) {
                      console.warn('buffer: ', [buf]);
                      const fileData = {data:[buf], name:name, type:mimeType};
                      results.push(fileData);
                      console.warn('results of file: ', fileData);
                  });
          }
         console.warn(results);
         return results;
     }
```

then I put it in an data object to send to my server via axios this is what that data object looks like

```
const data = {
           Name: asset[0].name,
           Detail: asset[0].detail,
           Files: asset[0].files.fileList
      };
```

When I console out the Files it shows there is Arraybuffer data in it. But when I send it to my server it looks like that data is stripped out of the header call. Cause when I look at the header I no longer have that data in there and I cannot figure out why that is happening.

this is my axios call.

```
axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/Assets', data)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

and my back end web api post controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAsset([FromBody] AssetSaveRequest request,[FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(ms);
                        var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                        // act on the Base64 data
                    }
                }
            }

            var assetCreationDto = new AssetCreationDto(request);
            //var assetCreationDto = "";
            

            try
            {
                var asset = _mapper.Map<Asset>(assetCreationDto);
                _context.Assets.Add(asset);
                //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var assetDto = _mapper.Map<AssetDto>(asset);

                return CreatedAtAction("GetAsset", new {assetDto.Id}, assetDto);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException dbe)
            {
                var errorCode = ((Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException) dbe.InnerException).SqliteErrorCode;
                switch (errorCode)
                {
                    case 19:
                        Console.WriteLine(((Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException)dbe.InnerException).Message);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            return null;


        }
```

That of which I don't know is working because I never get the file data, I do how ever get the Name and the details which come in fine.

I am looking for advice on what I should do here to get this to work. I have tried converting the arraybuffer to base64 string but that does not come out right any help and suggestions would be great to get me back on track with this project .

UPDATE:
I have modified my srcToFile code to give me a file, now I am using axios to send the file and data to the backend working with one file at this time and all im getting in the header now is [object object]. I've tried JSON.stringify on my data like so

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
           Name: asset[0].name,
           Detail: asset[0].detail,
           Files: asset[0].files.fileList
       });
```

It stringify's the name and detail but wipes out the file and I get nothing on the backend.

I have tested with postman and made several successful posts. but I can't seem to get the correct data from my Vue front end.

that is where I am at now. any suggestions always helps

Comment: Send Blobs and Files via [FormData with the XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

Comment: If you want to pass List<IFormFile> with formdata,you can do like this:`var pdata = new FormData();

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                pdata.append('files', files[i]);
            }`